# C++ container for fixed-size array set at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a simulation code whose bottleneck is running 3 nested for loops over a block of data that acts like a 3D array pointed to by a variable like `double ***three_d_arr` and doing mathematical operations on each value. I don't know the array size at compile time. The array size is determined at runtime, and never gets resized. I'd like to get an idea of whether it's worth switching to a C++ container to get rid of my `***`'s. I looked around at a lot of discussions of bare arrays vs std::array vs boost::array vs std::vector, and all the discussions I could find looked at cases where 1) the array size is fixed and known at compile time, or 2) the array size dynamically changes throughout the code. I couldn't find discussions that matched my case. With my case, what are my best options for renouncing [Three Star Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) without sacrificing speed?

Comment: Blitz++ is a C++ library made for doing high-performance work with arrays. Might be worth checking it out.

Comment: Cross off `std::array`. It's compile-time sized. `vectors` of `vectors` have no guaranteed contiguity and may result in performance-crippling cache misses as your code bounces from one vector to another scattered throughout memory. `boost::array` I don't know enough of to comment on. Me, I'd research `boost::array` a bit to see how it works, then possibly head off to make a wrapper class that makes a 1D vector look 3D. That way I get the desired 3D indexing and the tight spatial locality of a 1D array.

Comment: It's impossible to say with out profiling. There are also numerous libraries for matrix computation. You need to port representative samples, run, compare, and choose. Writing it properly and enabling possible optimizations is crucial for performance.

Comment: Problem with `double ***` is that the compiler has no knowledge of the first two layers of deference so assumes the last layer aliases. Also it prevents the compiler from using linear indexing using pointer increment. Point is, if your code as a critical loop along one of the array dimensions, optimize that dimension and forget about the other two. If that critical loop is written in C with `restrict`ed pointers, the actual container matters even less.

Comment: Some people like `std::valarray`s and `std::(g)slice`s.